# LWC Datatable with mass edit functionality

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-development

Can custom data types be used to create an empty row for the lightning datadatable where values from the top row would copy to all rows below? Is this functionality achievable or should I use a different component?

[image: Sample Table]

Thank you,

Comment: We also have same components available using LWC: https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/03/24/lightning-web-components-datatable-with-lazy-loading-inline-edit-and-dynamic-row-action/

Answer (score 2):

Custom Data Types cannot be used to create a row. It is a data type - similar to `text`, `number`, `action`, etc. And data types are used to specify what will displayed in a column (e.g. you can create a data type that will display another component inside of a column).

For your purposes you cannot use `lightning-datatable` and will have to stay with regular HTML-based table. [Here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/) you can see several examples of how to prepare such component.

Comment: For anyone looking for this in the future I did find a similar way to mass edit rows but this was done with aura components. https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/01/01/lightning-datatable-lazy-loading-with-inline-editing-and-actions/